# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int - php

Tags: php, pagination

I am using a pagination class in my project. The problem is when i load `index.php` it gives me a notice i.e

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int on Line 14

How to resolve it?

**Pagination.class.php**

```
class PerPage {
    public $perpage;

    function __construct() {
        $this->perpage = 2;
    }

    function perpage($count,$href) {
        $output = '';
        if(!isset($_GET["page"])) $_GET["page"] = 1;
        if($this->perpage != 0)
            $pages  = ceil($count/$this->perpage); // Line 14
        if($pages>1) {
            if(($_GET["page"]-3)>0) {
                if($_GET["page"] == 1)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=1 class="current-page">1</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="button" class="perpage-link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . '1\')" value=1 />';
            }
            if(($_GET["page"]-3)>1) {
                    $output = $output . '...';
            }

            for($i=($_GET["page"]-2); $i<=($_GET["page"]+2); $i++)  {
                if($i<1) continue;
                if($i>$pages) break;
                if($_GET["page"] == $i)
                    $output = $output . '<span id='.$i.' class="current-page">'.$i.'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="button" class="perpage-link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href . $i . '\')"  value=' . $i . ' />';
            }

            if(($pages-($_GET["page"]+2))>1) {
                $output = $output . '...';
            }
            if(($pages-($_GET["page"]+2))>0) {
                if($_GET["page"] == $pages)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=' . ($pages) .' class="current">' . ($pages) .'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="button"  class="perpage-link" onclick="getresult(\'' . $href .  ($pages) .'\')"  value=' . $pages . ' />';
            }           
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

**PerPage.php**

```
<?php
include "dbcontroller.php";
    function perpage($count, $per_page = '10',$href) {
        $output = '';
        $paging_id = "link_perpage_box";
        if(!isset($_POST["page"])) $_POST["page"] = 1;
        if($per_page != 0)
        $pages  = ceil($count/$per_page);
        if($pages>1) {

            if(($_POST["page"]-3)>0) {
                if($_POST["page"] == 1)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=1 class="current-page">1</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="1" />';
            }
            if(($_POST["page"]-3)>1) {
                    $output = $output . '...';
            }

            for($i=($_POST["page"]-2); $i<=($_POST["page"]+2); $i++)    {
                if($i<1) continue;
                if($i>$pages) break;
                if($_POST["page"] == $i)
                    $output = $output . '<span id='.$i.' class="current-page" >'.$i.'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="' . $i . '" />';
            }

            if(($pages-($_POST["page"]+2))>1) {
                $output = $output . '...';
            }
            if(($pages-($_POST["page"]+2))>0) {
                if($_POST["page"] == $pages)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=' . ($pages) .' class="current-page">' . ($pages) .'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="' . $pages . '" />';
            }

        }
        return $output;
    }

    function showperpage($conn,$sql, $per_page = 10, $href) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count   = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $perpage = perpage($count, $per_page,$href);
        return $perpage;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea have class method and class member (var) with the same name 'perpage'

Comment: then what will be the alternate?

Comment: Please, use different names. $var_perpage for var, for example. Maybe be same names confusing PHP.